# How to sort numbers in ascending order in a file in python (by insertion sort)

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, insertion-sort, data-files

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to sort numbers in ascending order from a file using python.

This is what I have got so far - but it doesnt seem to work!

```
input_file = open('C:\\Users|\Desktop\\data.txt') 
for line in input_file:
    print line

print('Before: ', input_file)
insertion_sort(input_file)
print('After : ', input_file)
def insertion_sort(items):
    """ Implementation of insertion sort """
    for i in range(1, len(items)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and items[j] < items[j-1]:
            items[j], items[j-1] = items[j-1], items[j]
            j -= 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I can already see two errors that would cause this script not to work

Answer (score 0):

You just have some grammatical errors:

- you should declare the `insertion_sort` function before use it
- you can't print a `File` type, you should make a `List` to read the file content, then sort the `List`, return the `List` and print the `List`
- your file name maybe wrong, use `/` is better in Windows

Try this:

```
input_file = open('C:/Users/Desktop/data.txt')

lst = []
for line in input_file:
    lst.append(int(line.strip()))

def insertion_sort(items):
    """ Implementation of insertion sort """
    for i in range(1, len(items)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and items[j] < items[j - 1]:
            items[j], items[j - 1] = items[j - 1], items[j]
            j -= 1
    return items

print('Before: ', lst)
print('After : ', insertion_sort(lst))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.  Code only answer can end up getting deleted.